# Automation testing with no URL

Tags: selenium, testing, automation

We are provided with gherkins and asked to create feature files and perform automation testing when only UI prototypes are available and there is no URL provided. Is there a way to perform testing when there is no url available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "write" tests when there is no URL available by using the Gherkin format. Here's an example for some calculator tests:

```
Feature: Scenarios for the Calculator App

  Background:
    Given Open the Calculator App

  Scenario: Pressing "C" outputs "0"
    When Press C
    Then Verify output is "0"

  Scenario: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
    When Press C
    And Press 1
    And Press +
    And Press 2
    And Press +
    And Press 3
    And Press +
    And Press 4
    And Press +
    And Press 5
    And Press =
    Then Verify output is "15"

  Scenario: 6 × 7 × 8 × 9 = 3024
    When Press C
    And Press 6
    And Press ×
    And Press 7
    And Press ×
    And Press 8
    And Press ×
    And Press 9
    And Press =
    Then Verify output is "3024"
```

(The above examples of a Gherkin feature file were taken from the [SeleniumBase Behave-BDD examples folder](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/tree/master/examples/behave_bdd), which I wrote. It requires a [steps file](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/behave_bdd/features/steps/calculator.py) with definitions in order to work.)

Comment: Thank you! But we are provided with mock screens and asked to perform testing. Since there is no valid URL, we will not be able to use the elements. For example, we have a user login page (mock screen without URL). How do we perform testing for it ?

Comment: You can't test something that doesn't exist, but you can write tests in advance for it.

Comment: Could you please suggest some blogs or sources to learn more. I have started learning 3 months back and still trying to understand things.

Comment: There's this tutorial: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/behave_bdd/ReadMe.md, which links to other tutorials such as https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html